# LLVM: Access Global Variable from Function Pass

Tags: llvm, llvm-c++-api

In learning the LLVM framework, I am trying to implement an 'optimization' pass that prints the name of each method at runtime when the method is called.

I read that global variables should only be created in a Module Pass, and I create the strings there (one per function), with

```
Constant* data = ConstantDataArray::getString(M.getContext(), F.getName());

GlobalVariable* gvar =
  new GlobalVariable(M, 
                     data->getType(), 
                     true,  
                     GlobalValue::ExternalLinkage, 
                     data, 
                     "fname_" + F.getName().str());
```

This works fine, insofar as the strings are laid out correctly in memory in the assembly file generated by the 'optimized' bitcode.

However, I have not found a way to insert calls to print these strings in the Function Pass. 
I want to use

```
Value* string = F.getValueSymbolTable().lookup("fname_" + F.getName().str());
CallInst* call = builder.CreateCall(emitPutS(string, builder, &TLI));
```

but `string` comes back as `NULL`. Is there a better way to look up global variables from a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out:

Basic blocks have a `getModule()` method, and modules have a `getGlobalVariable(StringRef Name)` method.

Alternatively, `IRBuilder:CreateGlobalStringPtr(...)` can be called from the function pass, and the `Value*` returned can be passed to `emitPutS(...)` directly. The module pass was not necessary.

Note, `CallInst* call = builder.CreateCall(emitPutS(string, builder, &TLI));` is incorrect. `emitPutS(...)` will create the call in the basic block already. The `CreateCall` is erroneous.